# CSS grid with fewest columns and rows to fit on screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I would like my grid to respond to the view size and to the number of items.  It should spread out the items using the fewest columns and rows which can fit in the browser window (100vh 100vw).

Currently I have this with css grid:

```
|-------|   |-----------|   |--------------------|   |--------------------|   |--------------------| 
| [] [] |   |[] [] [] []|   |[] [] [] [] [] [] []|   |[] [] [] [] [] [] []|   |[] [] [] [] [] [] []|
| [] [] |   |[] [] [] []|   |[] []               |   |[] []               |   |[] []               |
| [] [] |   |[]         |   |                    |   |                    |   |--------------------|
| [] [] |   |           |   |                    |   |--------------------|
| []    |   |           |   |                    |        
|-------|   |-----------|   |--------------------|
```

I would like this (with cols and rows spaced evenly over the available screen size,  and only if unable to fit, then show vertical scroll-bar):

```
|-------|   |-----------|   |--------------------|   |--------------------|   |--------------------| 
| [] [] |   |  []   []  |   |   []    []    []   |   |   []    []    []   |   | []  []  []  []  [] |
| [] [] |   |  []   []  |   |                    |   |   []    []    []   |   | []  []  []  []     |
| [] [] |   |  []   []  |   |   []    []    []   |   |   []    []    []   |   |--------------------|
| [] [] |   |  []   []  |   |                    |   |--------------------|
| []    |   |  []       |   |   []    []    []   |   
|-------|   |-----------|   |--------------------|
```

I tried to hack something with media queries, but it is tedious.  Is there an automatic way?

```
.switch-panel {
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.switch {
   height: 116px;
   width: 116px;
}

/* Mobile-first: Tablet and larger */

@media all and (min-width: 700px) {

    /* minimum 3 columns */

    .switch-panel {
        grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 1fr) repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    }
}

@media all and (min-height: 419px) {

    /* minimum 2 rows */

    .switch-panel {
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto;
    }

}

/* Mobile-first: Desktop and larger */

@media all and (min-width: 960px) {

    /* minimum 4 columns */

    .switch-panel {
        grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 1fr) repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    }
}

@media all and (min-height: 767px) {
    /* minimum 3 rows */

    .switch-panel {
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr auto;
    }

}
```

Please try my example code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vj9n7r4w/1/

Comment: While this may be a largely theoretical question (and, if so, those don't necessarily do so well here since we're more about providing answers to actual real-world problems however abstracted they may be when posed to [SO]) could you please post some minimal HTML to which we can apply your CSS and reproduce your problem?

Comment: added jsfiddle, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

CSS grids can be flexible and adaptive without the use of media queries. Something like this should work. Set the height to whatever you want.

```
body {
display: grid;
height: 400px;
grid-gap: 1rem;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

And you can checkout http://1linelayouts.glitch.me/ from google for some quick, easy grid guides.

Comment: Your suggestion is essentially what I already have.  It is minimizing the number of rows, but not the number of columns.

Comment: "*There's definitely...*" - I'm curious. :)